# Filter dataframe by POINT

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm new to GeoPandas, and I have the coordinate points in a dataframe, and I want to filter by unique points, however, the following doesn't work:

```
time    depth   lat lon water_u water_v speed   direction   geometry    hour    day month   year
0   2020-01-01 12:00:00 8.0 18.00000000 288.96002197    0.04900000  0.06900001  0.08462861  35.38026428 POINT (288.960 18.000)  12  1   1   2020
1   2020-01-01 12:00:00 8.0 18.00000000 289.03997803    0.07800000  0.07800000  0.11030866  45.00000000 POINT (289.040 18.000)  12  1   1   2020
2   2020-01-01 12:00:00 8.0 18.00000000 289.11999512    0.08500000  0.03400000  0.09154780  68.19859314 POINT (289.120 18.000)  12  1   1   2020
3   2020-01-01 12:00:00 8.0 18.00000000 289.20001221    0.06200000  -0.01000000 0.06280128  99.16234589 POINT (289.200 18.000)  12  1   1   2020
4   2020-01-01 12:00:00 8.0 18.00000000 289.28002930    0.03000000  -0.04600000 0.05491812  146.88865662    POINT (289.280 18.000)  12  1   1   2020
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1578740 2020-10-21 09:00:00 8.0 18.39999962 290.55999756    0.12900001  0.01300000  0.12965339  84.24543762 POINT (290.560 18.400)  9   21  10  2020
1578741 2020-10-21 09:00:00 8.0 18.39999962 290.64001465    0.15200001  0.00100000  0.15200330  89.62306213 POINT (290.640 18.400)  9   21  10  2020
1578742 2020-10-21 09:00:00 8.0 18.39999962 290.71997070    0.16300000  -0.01000000 0.16330646  93.51068115 POINT (290.720 18.400)  9   21  10  2020
1578743 2020-10-21 09:00:00 8.0 18.39999962 290.79998779    0.12700000  -0.02600000 0.12963410  101.56996918    POINT (290.800 18.400)  9   21  10  2020
1578744 2020-10-21 09:00:00 8.0 18.39999962 290.88000488    0.06100000  -0.05000000 0.07887332  129.34051514    POINT (290.880 18.400)  9   21  10  2020
```

If I use the following as a string, it simply doesn't work:

```
d.geometry == "POINT (288.960 18.000)"
```

How the filtering works for this type of data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), .x, .y and round the coordinates:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/500kpoints.shp')

#The coordinates are truncated:

df.head(1)
0  0.0  POINT (471952.167 6264630.104)

#They actually have higher precision:

df.iloc[0]
geometry    POINT (471952.167213341 6264630.103706084)

df.loc[(df['geometry'].x==471952.167) & (df['geometry'].y==6264630.104)]
# :( nothing gets selected

#Try rounding them
df.loc[(round(df['geometry'].x, 3)==471952.167) & (round(df['geometry'].y, 3)==6264630.104)]
0  0.0  POINT (471952.167 6264630.104)
```